# Use of SqlDataReader Records After Disposal

Tags: c#, linq, dispose, sqldatareader

I would like to retrieve all `System.Data.IDataRecord`s from a `SqlDataReader`.  With LINQ, this is simple, but I'd like to be able to dispose of all SQL objects and keep the data intact.  Below is what I have:

```
private static List<System.Data.IDataRecord> getRecords()
{
    List<System.Data.IDataRecord> records;
    //Make a SqlConnection and SqlCommand.
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        records = reader.Cast<System.Data.IDataRecord>().ToList();
    }
    //Dispose of SqlCommand and SqlConnection.
    return records;
}
```

But here is my question:  When `getRecords()` is finished, I have my data, and I have asked for all SQL objects to be disposed.  But am I somehow hanging onto data which will prevent proper resource disposal?  Or will my data eventually become invalid once the garbage collector does its work?  I think the answer is no, but I am trying to find something definitive.  I believe `Dispose()` will only remove unmanaged resources, and since I placed the data in my List, I would think it is safe.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine.

`IDataRecord` instances are not affected by `SqlDataReader.Dispose` in any way. They contain their own full copy of the data and schema info, completely separate from the reader.

Comment: Really? I could have sworn that I ran in to a big bug a few years ago where I was letting a `IDataRecord` live outside of the scope of the reader and that was causing a problem. Never tried again after that happened.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain verified by looking in ILspy since it's not explicitly guaranteed in docs anywhere. Maybe it was not always so.

Comment: @CoryNelson, what you said confirms my thinking, but do you have a source for your statement?  Thanks.

Comment: @CoryNelson, I see your comment about verifying in ILspy.  That's good, but do you know of any official Microsoft statement regarding this sort of thing?

Comment: Like most of .NET, such details are not documented. Microsoft does have a history of maintaining undocumented functionality, so while it's not a sure thing, it's probably safe to assume.

Comment: @CoryNelson, I didn't want to keep dragging this out for you, so I accepted and up-voted your answer.  Now, could you explain how you can tell `IDataRecord` is not affected through ILSpy?

Comment: Open up ILSpy, check out `SqlDataReader.GetEnumerator()`. It copies all the relevant schema data in there.

Comment: @CoryNelson, wow.  Cool.  Thank you very much.  This has been enlightening.